# The options loop in channel entries form does not accept an offset

Tags: safecracker, loop

I'm trying to add an offset parameter to the options loop within a Channel Entries form. While it accepts a limit, it simply ignores the offset. Here's an example:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="channel1"}
  {options:channel_name limit="4" offset="4"}       
    {option_name}
    # limit="4" works, offset="4" doesn't 
  {options:channel_name}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

**How can I add an offset?** I'm using this on a channel form.

Comment: Hi Franz, I see you've made this to a new question! :) Can you let us know what type of field `channel_name` is? Is it a relationship field, checkboxes, select list or otherwise? I was going to write a quick example to see if I could debug this. interesting that `limit` works, looking through the code I don't even see it being supported!!!!

Comment: Hi @Blatant! Thanks for your help :) This is a relationship field rendered using radio buttons. I also found it interesting that `limit` works while `offset` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

A word of warning, you could achieve this with PHP on a template (though some here don't like the idea of PHP on templates!).

Instead of tring to use the limit/offset syntax, lets push out options into a PHP array, then we'll do the array limits and offsets ourselves!

**PHP On = Output**

```
<?php
$options = array();
function print_options($limit, $offset){
  foreach( array_slice($options, $offset, $limit, true) as $option ) { 
    print $option;
  }
} 
?>
{exp:channel:form channel="channel1"}
  {options:channel_name}       
    <?php $options[] = '<option value="{option_value}">{option_name}</option>'; ?>
  {options:channel_name}

  <select>
    <?php print_options(4, 4); ?>
  </select>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Untested but hopefully you'll get the idea if I've not type-o'd in my code...

**Edit**: Simpler version, removed unneeded function and potential var scope issue.

**PHP On = Output**

```
{exp:channel:form channel="channel1"}
  {options:channel_name}       
    <?php $options[] = '<option value="{option_value}">{option_name}</option>'; ?>
  {options:channel_name}

  <select>
    <?php 
      //array_slice parameters = options array, limit, offset, preseveKeys
      foreach( array_slice($options, 4, 4, true) as $option ) { 
        print $option;
      }
    ?>
  </select>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I've turned PHP On, parsed on output. Here's the PHP error I get: `A PHP Error was encountered; Severity: Notice; Message:  Undefined variable: options; Filename:; libraries/Functions.php(688) : eval()'d code; Line Number: 209`. Here's the full error list: https://gist.github.com/franzos/c8d057e9f0632253f7f9

Comment: Looks like a PHP scope issue, try adding the `$options` array to the parameters of the `print_options` function and passing it in, Or see my edit which gets rid of the function, not really needed.